# The relationship between the number of samples and underfitting

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, overfitting

I am using [MLPClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html). The model consists of 3 hidden layers each of 128 neurons. The input dataset has 1 million points each of dim = 128. After playing around MLPClassifier parameters, I still get poor prediction accuracy. I am not sure if this is caused by underfitting or not! Can underfitting be caused by the lack of enough data during the training process?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you compare train/validation loss? If both are large it could be underfitting. Although, 1 million points seem like a lot of data.

To make sure that your code is correct I would suggest to overfit the model - pick a small part of your dataset and see if train loss goes to zero (and accuracy goes to 1).